# How do I delete the last record inserted into a MySQL table using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, delete-row, corresponding-records

How do I use PDO to delete the last row inserted (this was done in another class)?

I have this, but I don't know what else I'm supposed to do with it:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM Resources');
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: There is no first or last row in database. You need to specify certain row

Comment: I mean the last record I created in the DB

Comment: Also, may I ask why do you want to delete right after insertion?

Comment: Do you have inserted row id by chance?

Comment: @YourCommonSense because I'm using an "undo" function. :)

Comment: @NojoRu do you have the last ID that was created stored somewhere

Answer (score 2):

After inserting a new record, you get the ID like this:

```
$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Resources (data) VALUES (:data)");
$insert->execute(array(':data' => $data));
$lastid = $pdo->lastInsertID();

// delete last entry
$delete = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM Resources WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
$delete->execute(array(':id' => $lastid));
```

Comment: Do these need to be in the same class? I ask because I have an undo button that is used to delete the last inserted record.

Comment: @NojoRu to delete the last inserted record and to undo certain insert action are two **different** matters. It can be whatever class or method or PHP script as long as it can have the very id that was inserted.

Comment: Thought so. I got it working. I stored the value of PDO::lastInsertId in a session variable.